# Creating slider similar to McDonald's page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, slider

Hi can someone tell me how to create slider similar to http://mcdonalds.com.au/our-food/menu/#/breakfast (burgers slider) when hover on left or right side the images will slide to side...

Comment: Wow been waiting for a minute and that site is still loading...

Comment: Why do ad people like those damn things so much? They suck. They suck complete and total @ss. FFS, it's called a carousel and use some !@#$ing buttons on it for the love all that's nonsucky in UI. Sorry. You have my complete sympathy for having to work with anybody that's wanting to emulate McDonald's UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of jQuery sliders out there. I'll keep looking, the closest I've seen so far is:

http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

Comment: eh - that seems like the best one out there at the moment. I haven't seen many more like it.